# R: mtmm() command of psy package

Tags: r

I use R and mtmm() of psy package. In the documentation is referred that "Likewise, the correlation of an item with the global score of its subscale should be above its correlations with the global score of the other subscales." How can we calculate the global score of a subscale?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The mtmm function produces a table with columns that are called 'scale1', 'scale2', etc. These represent the global scores you are looking for, if I am not wrong about your question(?). In the cells you see the correlations with the items of all the subscales.